# How can I print the tree structure of subparsers of an argparse parser in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tree, command-line-interface

I'm working on a Python project that uses the `argparse` module to handle command-line arguments. I would like to print the tree structure of the `subparsers` associated with my main parser, so I can easily visualize the hierarchy of available commands.

Some requirements I have in mind for this functionality are:

1. It should be able to handle subparsers defined with `add_subparsers`.
   Each subparser should be identified by its name and should include any associated options.
2. The tree structure should be printed in a readable and well-formatted manner.
3. I've tried implementing this behavior using argparse, but I'm stuck at the stage of printing the tree structure.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, I managed to develop a solution to print the tree structure of `subparsers` of an `argparse` parser in Python. This solution is implemented using a recursive function that traverses the `subparsers` and prints the tree structure.

```py
def __option_strings_formatter(parser) -> str:
    retStr = ""
    if parser._optionals:  # Add options if present
        options_str = []
        positional_str = []
        for action in parser._optionals._actions:
            if isinstance(action, argparse._SubParsersAction):
                continue  # Skip argparse._SubParsersAction because tree vision use it to move
            pars = []  # Init Str
            if action.option_strings:  # if optional argument, add option selector, short priority
                pars.append(f"{action.option_strings[0]}")
            # MetaVar of option, custom or default
            if action.metavar:
                pars.append(f"{"...".join(action.metavar)}" if not isinstance(action.metavar, str) else f"{action.metavar}")
            elif (action.nargs or action.required) and action.dest:
                pars.append(f"{action.dest.upper()}")
            # Add to the right list only if something are present
            if pars:
                parStr = " ".join(pars)
                parStr = f"{parStr}" if action.required else f"[{parStr}]"
                options_str.append(parStr) if action.option_strings else positional_str.append(parStr)
        # Order the list and add to line
        if positional_str:
            positional_str.sort()  # Order to keep before required parameters and positional arguments
            retStr += " " + " ".join(positional_str)
        if options_str:
            options_str.sort()  # Order to keep before required parameters and positional arguments
            retStr += " " + " ".join(options_str)
        return retStr


def subparserTree(parser: argparse.ArgumentParser, start="", down=("│", " "), leaf=("├", "╰"), item=("┬", "╴"), indInc=1) -> str:
    subparsers_actions = [action for action in parser._actions if isinstance(action, argparse._SubParsersAction)]
    strOut = f"{parser.prog} {__option_strings_formatter(parser)}\n" if not start else ""
    for subparsers_action in subparsers_actions:
        for choice, subparser in subparsers_action.choices.items():
            endSublist = choice == list(subparsers_action.choices.keys())[-1]
            strOut += start + (leaf[endSublist] + "─" * indInc)
            retString = subparserTree(subparser, start=start + (down[endSublist] + " " * indInc), down=down, leaf=leaf, indInc=indInc)
            strOut += item[0] if retString else ""
            strOut += item[1] + choice + __option_strings_formatter(subparser) + "\n" + retString
    return strOut
```

To use this function, simply call it with the main parser and print the result:

```py
print(subparserTree(parser))
```

The output, in my case, is:
[image: Format tree output]

If you have any improvements to propose, I would be very happy to accept them!

Answer (score 0):

I created [abstracttree](https://pypi.org/project/abstracttree/), which is a generic library for visualizing trees.
I tried it on your problem.

First create a nested subparser:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')

# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')
```

Now to visualize it:

```py
from abstracttree import astree, print_tree

def get_subparsers(parser):
    # Extracted from answer by Emanuele Alfano
    for action in parser._actions:
        if isinstance(action, argparse._SubParsersAction):
            yield from action.choices.values()

tree = astree(parser, children = get_subparsers)
print_tree(tree)
```

The result looks as follows:

```
ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
├─ ArgumentParser(prog='PROG a', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
└─ ArgumentParser(prog='PROG b', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

You can customize how each ArgumentParser should be printed using the `formatter`-option.
You can also pass the keyword `style=` to print it in a different style.